# What is use of sh ''' <command > ''' - three ticks - in a Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, sh

I have a Jenkinsfile which uses three tick marks surrounding a command to execute as in:

```
sh ''' command '''
```

We have no idea why three tick marks are required or what role they perform.
This syntax is seen in the Jenkinsfile doc set.

Comment: In *bash*, `'''` is 100% identical to `'`; there is no difference whatsoever. Either there's different meaning in Jenkins, or the author was coming from a different language like Python where triple-quotes *are* meaningful, and forgot that in POSIX-y shell languages they aren't.

Comment: BTW, note that `bash` and `sh` are different interpreters, implementing different languages (even when bash is called under the `sh` name, it disables some functionality to hew closer to the POSIX sh standard); thus, a question about `sh` should generally be tagged as such.

Answer (score 10):

This has nothing at all to do with bash (in which triple-quotes have no special meaning at all), and everything to do with Groovy (the separate, non-bash interpreter that parses [Jenkinsfiles](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/)).

In Groovy, but not in bash, strings must use triple-quotes to span multiple lines.

In the context of a `sh` directive in a Jenkinsfile, the *content* of your triple-quoted string is passed to a shell as a script to execute; however, the *syntax* is parsed by Groovy, so it's only Groovy that cares about the quotes themselves (as opposed to the quoted content).

Answer (score 0):

Can you give more idea about what kind of command is it, is it a unix command or some script ?

The single quote and its variation like '''(3 ticks) as mentioned in question skip the variable expansion, and it could used to show what is being  executed.

```
echo '''Updating JAVA_HOME variable :
export $JAVA_HOME="$NEW_JAVA_HOME" '''
```

However  in your question, a command (some string) is enclosed between 3 ticks marks and sh tries to execute this command or script. One such example below

```
$ echo "echo hello" > /tmp/tesh.sh
$ sh '''/tmp/test.sh'''
hello
```

Comment: In pure bash, three ticks skip variable expansion *only to the exact same extent that one tick does*: Two of those ticks cancel each other out (opening and immediately-closing a single-quoted context, or closing and re-opening it if starting in such a context), so only the odd one has any effect.

Comment: ...as for "what kind of command it is", the OP says that in the question -- it's a [Jenkinsfile](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/) directive.